# Regex does not return all matches

Tags: .net, xml, regex

I have following XML based string:

```
<msg act='demo' lvalue='demo' msgtime='10/29/2000 2:12:52 PM' id='9969' />
```

I need to retrieve list of all attributes and their corresponding value. e.g.

```
act
lvalue
msgtime
id
demo
demo
10/29/2000 2:12:52 PM
9969
```

I tried \s\w+\= for getting attributes and it works okay. For attributes values, \='\w+'\s returns 
demo

```
demo
demo
9969
```

It is missing the msgtime attribute. I am assumign it is because of the spaces. I was wondering if someone can help me with the Regular Expression please.

Thanks,

Harit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return both attribute names and values in the order they appear on the string:

```
(?<==').*?(?=')|\w+(?==')
```

Result for `<msg act='demo' lvalue='demo' msgtime='10/29/2000 2:12:52 PM' id='9969' />`

```
act
demo
lvalue
demo
msgtime
10/29/2000 2:12:52 PM
id
9969
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you response. It really helped. I was wondering how can I get the value of the element. For example - in <msg act='demo'>Hello World!</msg> How can get this: msg Hello World!